# Need to call function after pausing execution

Tags: javascript, delay, execution

I have a scenario in which I am going to display news at a bottom bar in a web page.
I am calling a cgi script which will return the news as a string array of 4 elements max, at an interval of 10 seconds.

After receiving the array of news items, I am updating the bottom bar on every 2 seconds displaying 1 news item at time.
this is my code :

```
 function listenForNews(){   
    var xmlHttpReq = getXMLHttpReq();   
    var destinationURL = cgi+"/news.cgi";
    if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 0){
        xmlHttpReq.open('GET', destinationURL, true);
        xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
                if(xmlHttpReq.responseText != ""){
                    updateNews(xmlHttpReq.responseText);
                    t=setTimeout("listenForNews();",10000);
                }
            }
        }
        xmlHttpReq.send();
    }   
}

  //Pause JS execution for 2 seconds to display 1 item at a time
    function pause(ms) {    
        ms += new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date() < ms){}
    }
    //update text field after 2 sec
    function updateNews(buffer){
        for(var i=0;i<buffer.length;i++){
            document.getElementById('text').value = buffer[i] + " at "+ new Date();
            pause(2000);
        }
}
```

But the problem I am facing is I am not able to get exactly same scenario as I expect.
Actually the cgi call is itself delaying for more than 20 seconds each time (10 sec * 2 sec).

So on GUI, text filed is updated after approx 20 sec.
What I want is textfield should be updated every 2 sec as well as cgi call should be made on every 10 sec(with synchronized way)

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: That is a horrible way to *pause*. Use a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I can't use setTimeout since then it will overwrite previous 3 items and each time it will show only last 4th item...

Comment: You can, it would just take some refactoring. That pause method will certainly lock the browser during that period.

Comment: Thanks Can you please give an example of the same ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `pause` function like that will hang the browser, preventing it from redrawing the page.  Thus, nothing will appear to happen until that loop over `i` ends.  There are two simple ways to do this involving `setTimeout`s:

```
function updateNews(buffer, i)
{
    document.getElementById('text').value = buffer[i] + " at "+ new Date();
    if(i + 1 < buffer.length)
        setTimeout(function() {updateNews(buffer, i+1);}, 2000);
}
```

which would be called by `updateNews(xmlHttpReq.responseText, 0);`.  This chains the calls by having each one create the timeout for the next one.

```
function updateNews(buffer)
{
    var i;
    for(i = 0;i < buffer.length;i++)
        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('text').value = buffer[i] + " at "+ new Date();}, 2000 * i);
}
```

This one sets all of the timeouts at the beginning, using different lengths of time to space them out.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me...!!! But just one problem I am getting that `i` becomes NaN sometimes...

Comment: @adn295 Which method did you use?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is more appropriate here. Something like the following is closer to what you need:

```
function updateNews(buffer) {
  var el = document.getElementById('text'), idx = 0, len = buffer.length;
  setInterval(function () {
    el.value = buffer[idx %= len] + ' at ' + new Date;
    idx += 1;
  }, 2000);
}
```